# Gitlab: cannot create ssh key

Tags: git, gitlab

I have this error when I add ssh-rsa key:

The form contains the following error:
Key must be at least 4096 bits

To generate ssh-key (private and public) I execute ssh-keygen

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Look at `ssh-keygen`'s `-b` option to create bigger keys.

Comment: @barrycarter it doesn't work :( 
ssh-keygen -b
option requires an argument -- b
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile] [-m format]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa]
       ssh-keygen -p [-f keyfile] [-m format] [-N new_passphrase]

Comment: Er, yes, I meant `ssh-keygen -b 4096` or something-- I was suggesting you `man ssh-keygen` and look at the `-b` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing, you can use a passphrase-less key with, while specifying the number of bits in the key to create:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -P "" -f ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

If you need to copy the public key to GitLab, use the `~/.ssh/gitlab.pub` file content.

To test it, create a ~/.ssh/config file with:

```
Host gitlab
  Hostname gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

And `ssh -Tv gitlab` to check if you get a Welcome message, confirming you are properly authenticated.